# Recursive table formulating function that waits for page to load before each step

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, async-await

I am trying to find out how to have all of these things in the same function:

1. An array of objects where sections of it are generated through a time-consuming function
2. The DOM loading before each attempt at loading the next section of array objects

I have tried Promise, recursive functions to my best ability, to no prevail.
Here is the code I am manipulating:

```
showLoader();

      var preArray = new Array();
      var subjects = scrapeSubjects();

      function next(subject, prearray) {
          if (subject.length) {
            //Writes an element specifying the current section being loaded for the user on a loading page
              writeToLoader(subject[0]);
              $( document ).ready( function() { next(subject); });
              prearray = prearray.concat(pullData(subject.shift()));
          }
      };
preArray = next(subjects, preArray);

      var array = stripNonRooms(preArray, roomsArray);
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(array));
      //hides the loader when it is complete
      var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
      loader.style.display = "none";
```

Is there anything I can do to show the user the section that is currently being loaded, while it is being loaded?

Comment: Where are the promises in your code? Which part is actually asynchronous?

Comment: @Bergi can I not just use some sort of wait function before continuing my code?

Comment: No, you will need to use a specific wait function, and if you want to wait for something it'll be asychronous. But *what* in your code snippet above do you want to wait for?

Comment: @Bergi page ready, I have it specified, I only want to update a doc as I am running my code, so the user can see the div update as the code is running

Comment: The document does get ready only once. If you change something, that doesn't "un-ready" the page. If your problem is long-running code and the browser doesn't render your change soon enough, the only thing you can do is to make it asynchronous with a little timeout.

Comment: Try changing `$( document ).ready( function() { next(subject); });` into `setTimeout(function() { next(subject); });`

Comment: @Bergi changing a div content or adding elements within a ready function, will make the document not ready for a time, as long as the script is running, it will only be ready again after the script is complete, I was able to fix this using promises